# Is there a way to run a SQL Server docker image when starting my C# project in VS?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

As the title states, is there a way to run my SQL Server Docker container when I start my C# project in Visual Studio 2019?

I am using Docker Toolbox, and it is a Linux container. I am assuming there is a way to hook up a dockerfile somewhere? I don't want to containerize the entire app, just the SQL Server that I already have. I am using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Add a second project that launches the Docker container and use Multiple Startup Projects.

Comment: Do you already have SQL server dockerized?   Here is an article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Can you use something like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gabrielgrinberg.auto-run-command to run your `docker run` command to launch your image?

Comment: @DJordan Yes, it is already dockerized.

Comment: @NetMage But is there a way to do it without adding another project?

Comment: @JNevill I can, but I am hoping to use something that is already in VS or C# since this project is worked on by multiple devs

Comment: If I used Docker for Windows would that work better?

Comment: No, I don't think that matters. As far as I know, there is no provision to run a command or batch file before launching a startup project, so writing a simple program as a startup project is the best you can do.